# getting below error while doing ageing.process=true in jbilling

Tags: jbilling

```
 I am getting below exception while trying to change run ageing flag to true.





 Jbillng.property file 
    process.frequency=5 
    # if true, all the passwords in the system are encrypted with a one-way method 
    # if false, only root and clerk are encrypted, the rest are not (needed if 
    # you will show passwords to the users in the invoices/notifications or for the 
    # lost password feature). 
    password_encrypt_all=true 
    # the password that the user account is set to when a user is locked out (too many login retries) 
    lockout_password=totalSecret 
    # if the daily batch includes running the billing process 
    process.run_billing=false 
    # if the daily batch includes running the ageing process 
    process.run_ageing=true
```

Exception : 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2015-01-30 15:53:51,925 2095046 DEBUG [com.sapienter.jbilling.batch.ageing.AgeingProcessUserReader] (taskExecutor-6:) Entering afterPropertiesSet() 
2015-01-30 15:53:51,925 2095046 ERROR [com.sapienter.jbilling.batch.ExceptionSkipPolicy] (taskExecutor-6:) Skipping processing of user, exception: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.scopedTarget.scopedTarget.scopedTarget.ageingProcessUserReader' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/ageing-process-job-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:130)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:332)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:150) 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)

Answer (score 1):

Actually in jbilling telco  if you have more that 1 company this error is getting.

please tyr to remove other entities from database by replace is_deleted=1. and check whether you will get same error or not.

Answer (score 0):

AgeingProcessUserReader,can help if you share the code, because from the error what i see is , the problem is in the code. jbilling wouldn't complain about it if you just set the value true of process.agieng=true.

check this class "AgeingProcessUserReader"

Comment: I checked the issue and AgeingProcessUserReader but didn't get any solution. As per my knowledge JBilling does not handle ageing for more than one company. because i test it by creating another company. getting above error.

Comment: jbilling can handle multiple companies. it is built that way , check this table "ageing_entity_step", you will find a column called entity id. using this entity id jbilling can differentiate ageing steps for different companies. the concept of entity table is built for handling multiple companies, You can get in touch with here is my mail: debajyoti.bhattacharjee9@gmail.com, would be glad to help you out man!

Comment: "Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.scopedTarget.scopedTarget.scopedTarget.ageingProcessUserReader' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/ageing-process-job-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException at "

Comment: <------this part of the error is pointing to something different , check if you properly creating the bean. That's why you are getting an NullpointerException.

Comment: Check this file "resources.xml" if you configuring the bean property properly

Comment: i didn't create any bean. i just did process.agieng=true and also i know jbillinf supprt multiple companies. but for ageing i am getting this exception by adding new company. before adding new company the code wwas working fine and event were generating successfully. please check at your end. I am using jbilling telco edition.